# Update counter trigger PostgreSql

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a table like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id                                    | notification_sent | times_notification_sent
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4a1717a2-6e1e-4af6-aa34-8262899aa060  | t                 | 0
```

Here notification sent is boolean field and times_notification_sent is int. I am trying to create trigger which will increment the times_notification_sent by 1 when notification_sent is changed from true to false.

I am using following function and triggers but it not working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sent_counter_for_watch()  RETURNS TRIGGER 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$ BEGIN
IF OLD.notification_sent IS TRUE AND NEW.notification_sent IS FALSE THEN
   UPDATE "watch" SET "times_notification_sent" = "times_notification_sent" + 1 WHERE "id" = OLD."id";
END IF;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER "update_times_sent_counter" AFTER UPDATE OF "times_notification_sent" ON "public"."watch"
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.notification_sent IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.notification_sent)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "public"."update_sent_counter_for_watch"();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors:

You don't need an `update`, just assign the new value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sent_counter_for_watch()  
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$ 
BEGIN
  IF OLD.notification_sent IS TRUE AND NEW.notification_sent IS FALSE THEN
    new.times_notification_sent := old.times_notification_sent + 1;
  END IF;
  RETURN new;
END;
$$;
```

And you can't change the value in an `after update` triger, you need to change it to a `before` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "update_times_sent_counter" BEFORE UPDATE OF "times_notification_sent" 
  ON "public"."watch"
  FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.notification_sent IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.notification_sent)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "public"."update_sent_counter_for_watch"();
```

Comment: Both of you were correct. Thank you very much for your help.